# Regex - Limiting the amount of characters in a string

Tags: regex

This one is giving me trouble on my assignment.

Assume the alphabet of:

```
-any lowercase or uppercase letter
-0-9 decimal digits
-_
-$
-%
```

I want to write an expression that give me strings that:

```
-starts with a uppercase letter or one of the three symbols 
-can only have at most 6 lowercase or uppercase letters
```

I wanted to try something like

```
/^[a-z|_|$|%][a-z|A-Z|_|$|%]* {0,3}
```

but I'm having trouble with keeping track of the "at most" case depending on the initial character

edit: Sorry forgot examples.

```
_ababab <- OK
ab%$aaaa <- OK
_abababa <- NOT OK, because there is more than 6 alphabet characters
a$ababab <- NOT OK, because there is more than 6 alphabet characters
```

Comment: can you explain this `can only have at most 6 lowercase or uppercase letters`?

Comment: remove the `|` symbols which are present inisde the character class.

Comment: I would assume it means that there cannot be more than 6 lowercase or 6 uppercase letter in the string, including the first letter.

Comment: @user provide some examples of matched and unmatched strings..

Comment: Sorry added examples

Comment: the second ok example doesn't start with an uppercase letter

Comment: `starts with a uppercase letter or one of the three symbols `. Why the second string is true?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add something like `(?=.*[A-Z]{,6})(?=.*[a-z]{,6})`

Comment: What if the upper and lowercase letters are not consecutive?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
^[A-Za-z](?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*){5}$|^[_$%](?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*){6}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cH8vN2/4)